# Oauth2, getting Forbidden error (youtube analytics)

Tags: oauth2-playground

1.- I have created an app
     2.- Through Oauth2 I got the token for an user
     3.- I try to get the Youbute Analytics for the user's channel that authorized my app. But I have the error 403 (Forbidden). I do not have any clue ... can you help me?

Regards, P.

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)

Comment: 403 forbidden means you're not authorized / not logged in / you have no session cookie needed to access this address. My guess you left unchanged API key so it can't send data to your analytics account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Zydnar. What do you mean I left unchanged API key? I get the API key from google console and I can see the correct App in the authorization url. I test it both using java code and using the Oauth Playground page. In both cases the error is the same:

Comment: We can't help you without your code - too much guessing what could go wrong. Also please read FAQ how to post the question - look at this from reader point of view there is not enaugh data to post an answer. Check once more if the key is valid - so far it still look like there is something wrong with it (if not key itself, than it's scope (domain restriction).

Comment: Thanks Zydnar. Finally I found that I was trying with a not market account. I give the app permissions to the channel and now it works.